# Ошибка Copy Plugin

Tags: javascript

У меня вот такая проблема. 
Invalid options object. Copy Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options[0] misses the property 'patterns'. Should be:
   [non-empty string | object { from, to?, context?, globOptions?, toType?, force?, flatten?, transform?, cacheTransform?, transformPath?, noErrorOnMissing? }, ...]
(should not have fewer than 1 item). Это в файле webpack.config.js. Буду благодарен за помощь.
`new CopyPlugin([
            {from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/favicon.ico'), to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')}
        ]),`

Answer (score 7):

Попробуй так:

```
new CopyPlugin({ patterns: [{ from: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/favicon.ico'), to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/favicon.ico') }] }),
```